# PHP simple search between item range

Tags: php, mysql, search, between

First of all, before writing down PHP code. I have a table named as items in mySQL database.
Suppose it has the following reocrds inside **item_no** :

- 1L900BK
- 1L900BE
- 1L900BR
- 2L900BK
- 2L902BE
- 2L910PU

and the PHP code is :

```
require_once('connect_db.php');
$from = $_POST['from'];
$to = $_POST['to'];

$query = "SELECT * FROM items WHERE item_no BETWEEN '".$from."' AND '".$to."' ORDER BY item_no Asc";
$result = mysql_query($query);

if(mysql_num_rows($result)>0){
$num = mysql_num_rows($result);

for($i=0;$i<$num;$i++){
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
echo $row['item_no'];
echo "<br /><br />";    
}   
}
```

Now the problem starts here : Suppose I wanted to search for an item FROM **1l900bk** TO **2l900BK**, it will outputs all item_no between them ( 1L900bk 1L900BE ------- 2L900BK) Which is perfect!

But When i wanted to search for item_no FROM **1L9**  TO **2L9** ...The result or output is not correct ( 1L900BK - 1L900BE - 1L900BR - and stops !! ) Where is 2L900's ? It skips 2l9 when the for loop reaches this value.

Now all i want is to output all the 2l900's when i write down 2l9...I think there is something wrong with BETWEEN inside the query but i could not find an alternative way of doing it.

Thank You

Comment: What is the data type for item_no?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The result is correct as `"2L9" < "2L900BK"` is true. It's like a dictionary, you don't expect  to find `add` before `a`, do you?

You should try to use a substring of `item_no`, whose length equals the maximum length between `$from` and `$to`:

```
$from = $_POST['from'];
$to = $_POST['to'];
$length = max(strlen($from), strlen($to));

$query = "SELECT * FROM items WHERE SUBSTRING(item_no, 1, ".$length.") BETWEEN '".$from."' AND '".$to."' ORDER BY item_no Asc";
```

Answer (score 1):

It stops there because a comparison with strings is done alphabetically. This means **2L9** is less than **2L900**.

```
1L9 <= foo <= 2L9 <2L900
```

**foo** is all you will get in this case. Another example could be,

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE name BETWEEN "A" and "Bart"
```

You would get a name like Baracus, since **Bara** is less than "Bart", but not Bartholomew (which is alphabetically greater than Bart).

So if you want the 2L900, you will have to set the maximum possible element you want, i.e **2L900BR**

See [Binary Ordering](http://underpop.free.fr/m/mysql/teach-yourself/ch07lev1sec1.html)